# vba Class Property Values, setting default values, storing values to string

Tags: vba, class, variables, userform, listboxitem

another stumped newb here, trying to wrap my head around a problem.

I'm trying to use a class module, instead of public variables, with property get and set.
I want to set these values in a userform with text boxes, and update a listbox in the userform as they are entered, preferably on a text box event _afterupdate,
When the user hits the save button I'd like the profile attributes to be stored to a range.
No doubt this is going to be a laughable mess, but I've been stumped for days, and I'm coming here hat in hand. I just can't figure it out.

Class Mod Example:

```
Private mProfileName As String
Private mStartDate As Date
Private mEndDate As Date
Private mOngoing As Boolean


Sub Class_Initialise()
'Set default values for properties
             
 mLastName = "Enter Last Name"
 mStartDate = "Enter Date"
 mEndDate = Date
 mOngoing = True
End Sub
'********************************
'The relevant property procedures:
'********************************
Property Get ProfileName() As String
    ProfileName = mProfileName
End Property

Property Let ProfileName(Value As String)   
    mProfileName = Value
End Property

Property Get EndDate() As Date
    EndDate = mEndDate
End Property

Property Let EndDate (Value As Date)    
        mEndDate = Value    
End Property 

Property Get Ongoing() As Boolean
       Ongoing = mOngoing
End Property

Property Let Ongoing(Value As Boolean)

    If mEndDate = Date Then
    mOngoing = True    
    End If

End Property
```

In the Userform I currently have:

```
Option Explicit
'hopefully not needed:
'Private mTextBoxUpdated As Boolean
'Private mListBoxUpdated As Boolean
'Private mEnteredText As String
'Private mIndexText As String

Private DictThisForm As Dictionary
Private ProfileData As clsProfileData
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


    Debug.Print "UserForm Intialised"
    Set DictThisForm = New Dictionary
    Debug.Print "DictThisForm Created"
    Set ProfileData = New clsProfileData
   
    Call UserForm_UpdateListBox
```

And this laughable mess: (not even close to working)

```
Sub UserForm_UpdateListBox()
 
    With lbxListBox1
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 2
        
        .AddItem
        '.List(0, 1) = "Profile Name",ProfileData.ProfileName ' 
         'another attempt
        'the below throws a Type Mismatch Error
        .AddItem ProfileData.ProfileName, "Profile Name"
        .AddItem ProfileData.StartDate, "Start Date"
        .AddItem ProfileData.EndDate, "End Date"
        .AddItem ProfileData.OnGoing, "Ongoing?"
```

And (with privately declared module level variables)

```
Private Sub tbxProfileName_AfterUpdate()
 
    ProfileData.FirstName = tbxProfileName.Text
    enter code here
    Call UserForm_UpdateListBox

End Sub
```

At the moment I'm just trying to test the class module and see if I can get the properties values into a variable, or better, get those property values into a range on a hidden page, maybe via a dictionary, and update the list from there? Getting the property values into a listbox seems to be an unwieldy mess...

```
Sub testClassProfile()

    Dim getPropertyAsStringVar As String
    Dim NewProfile As clsProfileData

    Set NewProfile = New clsProfileData
    getPropertyAsStringVar = NewProfile.FirstName
    Debug.Print getPropertyAsStringVar

End Sub
```

Current Debug.Print output is "" ie zip. No default values.

Any advice greatly appreciated.
Please let me know if I'm asking too much at once and I'll try to narrow the scope of the question just to my current issue, I thought the context might be helpful...

Comment: Might be better to post a complete (but maybe smaller) example class - ie. some code we can run.  Just need the full class and that last test sub.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As a guess, it is probably an instancing issue.  In your `Sub TestClassProfile`, you create an instance of your `clsProfileData`.  But I suspect that you're not passing that to you UserForm to be populated.  In that, you are creating a separate instance of the class.  Try passing the instance crated outside to the userform.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your input... @TimWilliams Those two up there should run if they are pasted together into a class mod? Should I make them one unit?

Comment: @ainwood I'm actually trying to run the Userform from another module as much as possible, this was just a temporary thing to see if I could add the property values to the listbox, but I don't think that code is even correct, either that or the listbox doesn't accept class property values like that?
But I am very interested in how to pass an instance of 'clsProfileData' around - though, and this belies my ignorance, I thought a class instance and its properties would be ultimately be globally available? But part of the reason I dim's a new one was also so I could access the intellisense...

Comment: A custom class does not "auto-instance" - you need to create an instance before you can use it.  There's no globally accessible instance which get created just from having the class module present.  Probably worth skimming a couple of the many guides out there which cover using custom classes in VBA.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have the class dim'd in the declarations .... 
Then Set in the initalise sub... is this what you mean?

Comment: @TimWilliams updated to show declarations ...

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the Initialize method is

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
```

... that's not what you have so it will not be run when an object based on the class is created.  To make sure it's correct, inside your class code module select "Class" from the left-hand drop-down at the top, then select the required method from the right-hand selection.

Edit: this looks off -

```
Property Get Ongoing() As Boolean
       Ongoing = mOngoing
End Property

Property Let Ongoing(Value As Boolean)
    If mEndDate = Date Then
        mOngoing = True    
    End If
End Property
```

The `Ongoing` property doesn't really depend on the backing field or need to be set (since its value depends only on `mEndDate`, so you can drop the `Let` and just use a `Get` something like this -

```
Property Get Ongoing() As Boolean
       Ongoing = (mEndDate  <= Date)
End Property
```

Comment: Yes, that works fixed it.... Brilliant, can I use the class instance to update the listbox? 
like: `.AddItem: NewProfileData.Property, "property" `
Or do I need to pass it to a variable first?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an "answer", but it's too hard to respond to your comment with another comment!

Here is an example of how you can pass a class to a userform.  Might help!

The TestModule Code

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
'//Basic declaration of a UserForm
Dim testUF As UserForm1
Set testUF = New UserForm1

'//Now we create a test class - see the Property Get/Set for the string.
Dim testC1 As Class1
Set testC1 = New Class1
testC1.TestString = "Hello"

'//In the UserForm, I've created a property that accepts a class.  Assign the 
"TestClass" instance tothe UserForm Instance
testUF.Class1 = testC1
testUF.Show
End Sub
```

...And here is the userform.  Note the property that I've added to accept a class instance.

```
Option Explicit

Private classInstance As Class1
Public Property Get Class1() As Variant
    Set Class1 = classInstance
End Property

Public Property Let Class1(ByVal vNewValue As Variant)
    Set classInstance = vNewValue
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Me.Caption = classInstance.TestString
End Sub
```

And the class:

```
Option Explicit
Private mtest As String
Public Property Get TestString() As String
    TestString = mtest
End Property

Public Property Let TestString(ByVal vNewValue As String)
    mtest = vNewValue
End Property
```

When you run the "Test" code, you will see that instances of a class and a userform (which is actually just a "Class" as well) are created, and one instance is passed to another.  It is (behind the scenes) passed "by reference", so any changes made to TestCl within the userform would be retained outside of the class, allowing it to be modified by the UserForm, and then returned back to the controlling code for use later.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all that. I'll put all this in a new workbook and watch how it runs to try and get a better grasp...
It looks like you just pass it to a property in the userform... 
I had no idea that class instances could have other class instances as properties ! Thats some inception type craziness!
 I'm kind of only just grasping it. 
Thank you very much for your help.